# Vault - How can I get list of secrets by API request

Tags: security, keystore, development-environment, hashicorp-vault

Im new to hashicrop vault server. I need some general information's on the usage.

I created KV engines named **test**.

I want to list all secrets defined in this scope by api request.

> vault kv list test/

What is API equivalent of this CLI ?

Answer (score 3):

For that particular command, the API request would be

```
$ curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request LIST \
    https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/test
```

(assuming your server is running on your local machine). Note the `--request LIST` to perform a LIST request, and the `/test` at the end of the URL - that's the path where you created your engine (which is `secret` by default, but you have chosen `test`). Of course you will need to fill in the `...` with an actual token for this request to succeed.

The documentation you are looking for is here: https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/kv/kv-v1 (or for v2: https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/kv/kv-v2)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some API clients like Postman or Thunder Client, the use the following settings:

- Method: GET
- URL: https://vault.ai.cba/v1/kv/metadata/test/?list=true or https://vault.ai.cba/v1/kv/metadata/test/ and set query parameter list to true
- Set header X-Vault-Token to Vault token
- If the engine is KV v2, set header X-Vault-Namespace to

If you use Python requests, then use this:

```
requests.get(url, request_headers={"X-Vault-Namespace": <vault_namespace>}, params_body={'list': 'true'})
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the `X-Vault-Token` header? Can I log into the Vault GUI to generate one, or do I have to use the Vault CLI?